# Sharepoint 2010 Designer missing Master Pages from Site Objects

Tags: sharepoint-2010, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

How can I access the Master Pages link under Site Objects in SharePoint 2010 Designer when I am connected to the site remotely rather than being local?

When using Sharepoint Designer 2010 on the server itself with a local URL, I get the Master Pages link in the site objects so I can edit Master Pages.

However, accessing with the designer over the internet the Master Page link is missing.

Answer (score 6):

You can also find master pages in this path : `All files` -> `_catalogs` -> `masterpage`

Answer (score 1):

My user wasn't a member of the Farm Administrators group. This fixed it.